# How to do C++ development on Windows with Eclipse and CDT?

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I would like to do some C++ development on Windows using Eclipse and the [CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) plugin. I use Eclipse Helios and have installed the CDT plugin. But after that I can still not create a C++ project from `File > New > Project`, there is still only Java Project available there.

How to solve this? and do I have to install anything more for C++ development on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, see if the C/C++ perspective is available.  Go to `Window > Open Perspective > Other...` and you should see a C/C++ option.  If so, select it.  This will change the layout of the `File > New` menu by putting the C/C++ project options at the top level.

One other thing that has tripped me up before is the JRE that Eclipse is using.  I was using an older JRE (<1.5) and it would not allow me to use the CDT plugin until I upgraded.

You could check the Problems tab in the default perspective to see if Eclipse is having any problems loading its plug-ins.

As to the second question, you will probably need to install Cygwin or MinGW, which provide the compiler tools you will need to actually compile code.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seems like I have a C/C++ perspective. How do I get one?

Comment: Where do I find the "Problems tab"?

Comment: Problem solved, I have `Eclipse Helios` but now I downloaded `Eclipse Helios SR1` and then it worked better. I also downloaded MinGW. I typed in the program, but now I don't know how to compile it from Eclipse.

Comment: You should see a "Play" button.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an all-in-one download you can try [Wascana](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/wascana/) .It bundles Eclipse CDT and MingW preconfigured

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to install a recent version of Eclipse + CDT (Helios is very recent so maybe a less recent version is more stable), the GNU coreutils and MinGW separately.
At first it can appear tricky, however having to configure the projects gives a better understanding about how Eclipse, the coreutils and the dev tools (MinGW) work together.